# Hibernate : User is not mapped

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have been getting this error after generating the User class from database, everything seems to be in order in the User.hbm.xml yet I can't find why it's not mapped!

```
 SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/CCTVDATASET] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped [from User]] with root cause
        org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:189)
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:109)
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:95)
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:331)
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3633)
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3522)
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:706)
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:562)
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299)
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247)
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278)
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
            at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
            at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
            at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
            at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
            at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
            at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
            at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
            at com.journaldev.spring.dao.UserDAOImpl.listUsers(UserDAOImpl.java:42)
            at com.journaldev.spring.service.UserServiceImpl.listUsers(UserServiceImpl.java:35)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
            at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
            at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
            at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.listUsers(Unknown Source)
            at com.journaldev.spring.UserController.listUsers(UserController.java:31)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
            at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:500)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**User.java**

```
// default package
// Generated Nov 6, 2017 9:57:34 AM by Hibernate Tools 5.2.3.Final
package com.journaldev.spring.model;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * User generated by hbm2java
 */

public class User implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer iduser;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Integer ssoId;
    private Set logs = new HashSet(0);

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public User(String username, String password, Integer ssoId, Set logs) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.ssoId = ssoId;
        this.logs = logs;
    }

    public Integer getIduser() {
        return this.iduser;
    }

    public void setIduser(Integer iduser) {
        this.iduser = iduser;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Integer getSsoId() {
        return this.ssoId;
    }

    public void setSsoId(Integer ssoId) {
        this.ssoId = ssoId;
    }

    public Set getLogs() {
        return this.logs;
    }

    public void setLogs(Set logs) {
        this.logs = logs;
    }

}
```

**User.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
                                   "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Nov 6, 2017 9:57:34 AM by Hibernate Tools 5.2.3.Final -->
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class catalog="testdb" entity-name="User" name="User" table="user">
  <id name="iduser" type="java.lang.Integer">
   <column name="iduser"/>
   <generator class="identity"/>
  </id>
  <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="username" type="string">
   <column length="45" name="username" not-null="true"/>
  </property>
  <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="password" type="string">
   <column length="45" name="password" not-null="true"/>
  </property>
  <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="ssoId" type="java.lang.Integer">
   <column name="SSO_ID"/>
  </property>
  <set fetch="select" inverse="true" lazy="true" name="logs"
   sort="unsorted" table="log">
   <key>
    <column name="iduser" not-null="true"/>
   </key>
   <one-to-many class="Log"/>
  </set>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**UserDAO.java**

```
package com.journaldev.spring.dao;

import java.util.List;

import com.journaldev.spring.model.User;

public interface UserDAO {

    public void addUser(User u);
    public void updateUser(User u);
    public List<User> listUsers();
    public User getUserById(int id);
    public void removeUser(int id);
}
```

**UserDAOImpl.java**

```
package com.journaldev.spring.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.journaldev.spring.model.User;

@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDAOImpl.class);

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf){
        this.sessionFactory = sf;
    }

    @Override
    public void addUser(User u) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.persist(u);
        logger.info("User saved successfully, User Details="+u);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateUser(User u) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.update(u);
        logger.info("User updated successfully, User Details="+u);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<User> listUsers() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<User> usersList = session.createQuery("from User").list();
        for(User u : usersList){
            logger.info("User List::"+u);
        }
        return usersList;
    }

    @Override
    public User getUserById(int id) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();      
        User u = (User) session.load(User.class, new Integer(id));
        logger.info("User loaded successfully, User details="+u);
        return u;
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUser(int id) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        User u = (User) session.load(User.class, new Integer(id));
        if(null != u){
            session.delete(u);
        }
        logger.info("User deleted successfully, user details="+u);
    }

}
```

**UserService.java**

```
package com.journaldev.spring.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.journaldev.spring.model.User;

public interface UserService {

    public void addUser(User u);
    public void updateUser(User u);
    public List<User> listUsers();
    public User getUserById(int id);
    public void removeUser(int id);

}
```

**UserServiceImpl.java**

```
package com.journaldev.spring.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.journaldev.spring.dao.UserDAO;
import com.journaldev.spring.model.User;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private UserDAO userDAO;

    public void setUserDAO(UserDAO userDAO) {
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void addUser(User u) {
        this.userDAO.addUser(u);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void updateUser(User u) {
        this.userDAO.updateUser(u);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<User> listUsers() {
        return this.userDAO.listUsers();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public User getUserById(int id) {
        return this.userDAO.getUserById(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void removeUser(int id) {
        this.userDAO.removeUser(id);
    }

}
```

**UserController.java**

```
package com.journaldev.spring;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;


import com.journaldev.spring.service.UserService;
import com.journaldev.spring.model.User;

@Controller
public class UserController {

    private UserService userService;


    @Autowired(required=true)
    @Qualifier(value="userService")
    public void setUserervice(UserService us){
        this.userService = us;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/cctvsets", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listUsers(Model model) {
        System.out.println("CHECKPOINT 1");
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        System.out.println("CHECKPOINT 2");
        model.addAttribute("listUsers", this.userService.listUsers());
        System.out.println("CHECKPOINT 3");
        return "cctvsets";
    }
}
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**servlet-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->


    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="root" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Person</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.User</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                </beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="personDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.PersonDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="personService" class="com.journaldev.spring.service.PersonServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="personDAO" ref="personDAO"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="userDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.UserDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="userService" class="com.journaldev.spring.service.UserServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="userDAO" ref="userDAO"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.journaldev.spring" />


    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>


</beans:beans>
```

Comment: There's a comment in your `User` class that says "default package", however right under that you have a package declaration...

Comment: Thanks I corrected that. Doesn't solve the error though :P

Comment: Change the entity package to  import org.hibernate.annotations.Entity and try

Comment: I was hinting at the fact that you're not using a FQN for your class in your mapping.

Comment: @Codeminer Same error :(

Comment: @Kayaman Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: If your `User` class is in package `com.journaldev.spring.model`, it's not just `User`, it's `com.journaldev.spring.model.User`.

Comment: You can give the fully qualified name of your class in hbm file

Comment: @Codeminer not **can**, you **must**.

Comment: @Kayaman I changed it from  <class catalog="testdb" entity-name="User" name="User" table="user"> to
  <class catalog="testdb" entity-name="User" name="com.journaldev.spring.model.User" table="user"> And still the same error !

Comment: and do you have the mapping in the hibernate config file? What kind of tutorial are you following?

Comment: @Codeminer no need to change (or even use) `entity-name`. Please don't comment if you have no idea what to do.

Comment: @Kayaman I added <mapping resource="com.journaldev.spring.model.User.hbm.xml" /> to the hibernate config file and still gives the same error !

Comment: Well, at least the code is a lot less wrong than what it was in the beginning! Is there a good reason for not using annotations btw?

Comment: Well, I thought I'd generate the entities from database instead of writing them manually since I'm new to hibernate and never used annotation before

Answer (score 0):

You must mapped the User.hbm.xml in your Hibernate.cfg.xml.

Comment: I added <mapping resource="com.journaldev.spring.model.User.hbm.xml" /> In Hibernate.cfg.xml and still the same error

Answer (score 0):

In your JPQL query you need to use the full path to the user.

some thing like this:

```
List<User> usersList = session.createQuery("from com.journaldev.spring.model.User").list();
```

Answer (score -1):

User is a reserved work in mysql. Rename your table to e.g: 'SystemUser' or whatever you like, which is not a reserved keyword in mysql.

Comment: The table exists. The hbm was generated from the database schema. Using reserved words as table, column etc. names just requires you to escape them, it doesn't prevent you from using the name "User" completely in your database.